# PhpStorm помогите с настройкой

Tags: wordpress, phpstorm

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в PhpStorm включить autocomplete, чтобы дополнял так: пишу, к примеру, в файле `get_header();`, открываю рядом другой файл, там тоже надо написать `get_header` и PhpStorm мне это комплитит.

Версия PhpStorm 2018.1.

Пример из шторма
[image: phpstorm]

И вот, к примеру, из atom комплитит все что написано в single.php

[image: atom-1]

или вот другой пример

[image: atom-2]

Можно как-нибудь добиться чтобы phpstorn так же комплитил?

Comment: Ничего непонятно. Покажите на картинке, что ли.

Comment: И снова ничего непонятно. Никакого "рядом другого файла" на картиках не видно, autocomplete работает в PhpStorm. Что вас не устраивает? Пока вы не научитесь формулирвать свой вопрос так, чтобы он был понятен окружающим, вам никто не поможет.